# PHP: flattening array to access its keys directly

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have the following array:

```
foreach($items as $item)
{   
    //data coming from a feed     
    $published_on = $item->pubDate;
    $title = (string)($item->title);
    $link = (string)$item->link;

    $arrayFeed [] = array(
    date("j", strtotime((string)$published_on))."-".date("m", strtotime((string)$published_on))."-".date("Y", strtotime((string)$published_on)) => 
    $link."|".$title);

}
```

This stores:

```
    $arrayFeed
    : array = 
      0: array = 
        21-10-2014: string = http://myweb.com/21102014/|This is title 21-10-2014
      1: array = 
        25-09-2014: string = http://myweb.com/25092014/|This is title 25-09-2014
     .
     .
```

I access the link and title information by doing:

```
$arrayFeed[0]["21-10-2014"];
$arrayFeed[1]["25-09-2014"];
```

What do I have to change to access the data in this way?:

```
  $arrayFeed["21-10-2014"];
  $arrayFeed["25-09-2014"];
```

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your foreach should basically look like:

```
foreach($items as $item)
{   
    //data coming from a feed     
    $published_on = $item->pubDate;
    $title = (string)($item->title);
    $link = (string)$item->link;
    $date = date("j", strtotime((string)$published_on))."-".date("m", strtotime((string)$published_on))."-".date("Y", strtotime((string)$published_on));

    $arrayFeed[$date] = $link."|".$title;

}
```

Comment: If that worked for you please mark the answer as accepted so that no one else bothers to post another solution.